# Potentially Ambiguous Subject for a Verb in the Aeneid

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, aeneis, vergilius

Lines 405–407 of Vergil's Aeneid, Book 6, are as follows:

> Si te nulla movet tantae pietatis imago,
>   at ramum hunc" (aperit ramum qui veste latebat)
>   "agnoscas." Tumida ex ira tum corda residunt;

Context: Aeneas and the priestess are trying to cross the river to the Underworld, but living bodies are not permitted to cross. Thus, they present Charon with a the golden branch which allows them to enter the Underworld

My translation is:

> if no image of such great piety moves you,
>   but this bough" (she reveals the bough which was hiding in her clothing)
>   "you should recognise." Then the hearts swollen from anger settle;

After reading my translation over a few times, I came to wonder whether my translation of the section in parenthesis is actually correct. Could it be *"she reveals the bough which **she** was hiding in her clothing"*, or is the subject of *latebat* the bough as I currently have it?

Comment: I think there actually *is* an ambiguity here: whether *tumida* modifies *corda* or *ira*!

Comment: Oops, that's a typo on my part. It should be *irā* instead of *ira*, while *tumida* and *corda* are neuter plurals. I will add in the long marks!

Comment: @Brianpck is saying that it's metrically ambiguous. Because the a elides with *ex*, it could be long, modifying *ira*, or short, modifying *corda*. It of course makes better sense for *ex ira* to be dependent off *tumida*, but it's theoretically possible to go the other way.

Answer (score 11):

Grammatically, the subject must be the bough, because *qui*, the relative pronoun that refers to *ramum*, is nominative.

In the clause 'which she was hiding', 'which' is the direct object; so the relative pronoun would have to be accusative (*quem*). In addition, the verb would have to be transitive, which *lateo* isn't; it doesn't take a direct object (except in some relatively uncommon instances where it means 'to escape the notice of' or 'to be hidden *from*').

Still, if you're not aiming for a strictly literal translation, I think you'd be perfectly justified in translating as 'which she was hiding.' After all, the bough was unlikely to have snuck into her clothing on its own.

Answer (score 9):

English is unhelpful here, as "hide" can be transitive or intransitive. However, the verb *lateo, latere* is intransitive. It doesn't mean *to hide something*, but rather *to lie hidden* or *to be hidden*. It's intransitive, and thus does not take a direct object.

If you want the verb *to hide* as in *to conceal*, you'd want to use instead something like *celo, celare* or perhaps *contego, contegere*, words where the subject hides *something*, not *be hidden*.